# Locating objects (structs) in memory - how to?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

How would you locate an object in memory, lets say that you have a struct defined as:

```
struct POINT {
   int x;
   int y;
};
```

How would I scan the memory region of my app to find instances of this struct so that I can read them out?

Thanks R.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve by this?

Comment: How did those instances get lost in memory in the first place? Do you do `new POINT; new POINT;` and then try to find them?

Answer (score 4):

You can't without adding type information to the struct. In memory a struct like that is nothing else than 2 integers so you can't recognize them any better than you could recognize any other object.

Comment: ...and it's probably going to be hard even if you add type information (how would you know which bits represent type info?)

Comment: You would have to create a fairly unique sequence of bytes to recognize it (`0xDEADBEEF` anyone?)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  Structs don't store any type information (unless they have virtual member functions), so you can't distinguish them from any other block of sizeof(POINT) bytes.

Why don't you store your points in a vector or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have to know the layout to know what section of memory have to represent a variable. That's a kind of protocol and that's why we use text based languages instead raw values.

Answer (score 2):

You don't - how would you distinguish two arbitrary integers from random noise?

( but given a `Point p;` in your source code, you can obtain its address using the address-of operator ... `Point* pp = &p;`).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't.  Any (appropriately aligned) sequence of 8 bytes could potentially represent a POINT.  In fact, an array of ints will be indistinguishable from an array of POINTS.  In some cases, you could take advantage of knowledge of the compiler implementation to do better.  For instance, if the struct had virtual functions, you could look for the correct vtable pointer - but there could also be false positives.

If you want to keep track of objects, you need to register them in their constructor and unregister them in their destructor (and pay the performance penalty), or give them their own allocator.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to identify that struct. You need to put the struct somewhere it can be found, on the stack or on the heap.

Sometimes data structures are tagged with identifying information to assist with debugging or memory management. As a means of data organization, it is among the worst possible approaches.

You probably need to a lot of general reading on **memory management**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of doing this. The platform may specify some APIs which allow you to access the stack and the free store. Further, even if you did, without any additional information how would you be sure that you are reading a `POINT` object and not a couple of `int`s? The compiler/linker can read this because it deals with (albeit virtual) addresses and has some more information (and control) than you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Something like that would probably be possible on some "tagged" architecture that also supported tagging objects of user-defined types. But on a traditional architecture it is absolutely impossible to say for sure what is stored in memory simply by looking at the raw memory content.

You can come closer to achieving what you want by introducing a unique signature into the type, like

```
struct POINT { 
   char signature[8];
   int x; 
   int y; 
};
```

and carefully setting it to some fixed and "unique" pattern in each object of `POINT` type, and then looking for that pattern in memory. If it is *your* application, you can be sure with good degree of certainty that each instance of the pattern is your `POINT` object. But in general, of course, there will never be any guarantee that the pattern you found belongs to your object, as opposed to being there purely accidentally.

Comment: Do you know of an architecture that has a C++ compiler and supports any kind of tagging?

Comment: Including a checksum along with the signature could help prevent false positives - there is a chance that other data could contain a sequence of bytes that would be the same as the signature.

Comment: @Roger Pate: In real life? No, I don't.

Comment: Any in development, or what did you mean by "real life"?

Comment: @Roger Pate: No, I mean a C++ compiler for such a platform can exist. Whether there are any currently available - I don't know. I haven't seen one myself (and I don't really consider it relevant whether one really exists)

Answer (score 1):

What everyone else has said is true. In memory, your struct is just a few bytes, there's nothing in particular to distinguish it.

However, if you feel like a little hacking, you can look up the internals of your C library and figure out where memory is stored on the heap and how it appears. For example, [this link](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) shows how stuff gets allocated in one particular system.

Armed with this knowledge, you could scan your heap to find allocated blocks that were `sizeof(POINT)`, which would narrow down the search considerably. If you look at the table you'll notice that the file name and line number of the `malloc()` call are being recorded - if you know where in your source code you're allocating `POINT`s, you could use this as a reference too.

However, if your struct was allocated on the stack, you're out of luck.